# Bash regex not recognizing a single space " "

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I'm trying to solve a problem that appeared in my script which doesn't let me match the date+time (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) inside a for loop

```
list='"dt_txt":"2022-06-03 21:00:00"},'

regex_datehour='"dt_txt":"([0-9,-]*.[0-9,:]*)'




for i in $list; do
    [[ $i =~ $regex_datehour ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
```

It seems that the "`.`" between the two pair of brackets it's not recognizing the space! that's because inside of the list, if I replace the empty space between the date and the time by a `_`, it works as intended! `list='"dt_txt":"2022-06-03_21:00:00"},'`

desired output:

```
2022-06-03 21:00:00
```

what I get:

```
2022-06-03
```

Comment: Quote all variables as a good practice `[[ "$i" =~ "$regex_datehour" ]]`. Also, check script syntax and more on https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: It looks like you're using a regex to parse JSON. You should use a real JSON parser, like the `jq` utility.

Comment: Inside your `for` loop, add `echo $i`, you will see what `for` does.  It splits on the space...

Comment: @LMC: This is one of the few cases where you should *not* double-quote something, because if the pattern is quoted it's taken as a literal string rather than as a regular expression. Rayan Araujo: the only problem I see is that `for i in $list; do` will split on whitespace, and therefore run `"dt_txt":"2022-06-03` and `21:00:00"},` as separate items. As Barmar said, you should probably use a real JSON parser. Also, don't use `,` to separate things in a `[ ]` character set, so e.g. use `[0-9-]` instead of `[0-9,-]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is one that catches a lot of people, and that is whitespace breaking. In the `for` loop, your `$list` variable is not quoted, and it contains a space:

```
$ list='"dt_txt":"2022-06-03 21:00:00"},'
$ for i in $list ; do echo "i = $i" ; done ;
i = "dt_txt":"2022-06-03
i = 21:00:00"},
```

Make sure to put double-quotes around all strings that contain variables [except regexes](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2076):

Using an array for `list`, which is what makes sense when using the `for` loop from your original code, it would look something like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# filename: re.sh

list=(
  '"dt_txt":"2022-06-03 21:00:00"},'
  '"dt_txt":"2022-06-03 22:00:00"},'
  '"dt_txt":"2022-06-03 23:00:00"},'
)

regex_datehour='"dt_txt":"([0-9,-]*.[0-9,:]*)'

for i in "${list[@]}" ; do
    [[ "$i" =~ $regex_datehour ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
```

```
$ ./re.sh
2022-06-03 21:00:00
2022-06-03 22:00:00
2022-06-03 23:00:00
```

Comment: I appreciate all the help and critics, I know I should use an appropriate tool for parsing json, but I took that as a challenge.

@GordonDavisson I agree with you, I'm definitely not the type of programmer who copy and paste code. I really like to understand how it works before trying

Comment: @danielhoherd This is not my entire code! the real one does have an array, and I made this as an example just to show the problem

Comment: @RayanAraujo If it's a bash array, use `for i in "${list[@]}"; do`. If it's a JSON array... that's a lot more difficult. JSON allows recursive elements (e.g. arrays within arrays within arrays within...), so it (like [[X\]HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)) cannot be parsed with regular expressions.